# solve the typescript error while doing an cdk upgrade

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

Did a CDK upgrade to version 2.0 and ran npm install and the imported libraries worked fine.
However am facing issues in the code line  `Name: 'application-name'` below.

```
const nonplclAppNames = configs['nonplclAppNames'].split(',');
let nonplclAppNamesMatchingStatements: wafv2.CfnWebACL.StatementProperty[] = [];
nonplclAppNames.forEach((appName: string) => {
    const statement: wafv2.CfnWebACL.StatementProperty = {
         notStatement: {
             statement: {
                  byteMatchStatement: {
                      searchString: appName,
                          fieldToMatch: {
                              singleHeader: {
                                  Name: 'application-name' // <- Issue

                      .
                      .
                      .
```

```
Type '{ Name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IResolvable | SingleHeaderProperty | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'Name' does not exist in type 'IResolvable | SingleHeaderProperty'.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the interface for singleHeader changed and you need to use name instead of Name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACL.SingleHeaderProperty.html